# Uncompress and pipe the output to script

Tags: pipe, gzip

I have a script that takes an input with a `-i` flag. The input file I have is compressed (.gz). What I want to do (not sure it's possible), because the file is huge, do some thing like this:

```
gunzip -c myfile.gz | myScript.pl -i STDIN -o myoutfile.txt
```

So pipe the output of the decompression to my scripts input flag.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: that command I wrote doesn't work, I want something that will

Comment: well you have a space between `my` and `script`. If you used `-o` first and then `-i` it would work (remove the `STDIN`)

Comment: sorry about the space, that should not be there. The script is now giving me an error that I haven't provided an input. Does this have to be specifically specified in the perl script, if you want to do piping like this?

Comment: Never done perl, so I can't say.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
gunzip -c myfile.gz | myScript.pl -o myoutfile.txt -i -
```

it was the `-` after `-i` that did the trick.

Comment: To other readers, `-c` is for "to stdout"

Comment: I used the -k switch as well, to stop gunzip deleting the original file.